# Need help writing a REGEX to replace text and characters in matched items

Tags: html, regex, macos, textmate

I have large number of HTML files where I have to do a global search on all occurrences of href="" and perform the following on the contents inside the quotes:

%28 = remove

%29 = remove

%2C = remove

%26 = and

%20 = -

_   = -

.htm = .html

lowercase all caps

Any help from someone more knowledgeable in writing regular expressions would be greatly appreciated. I will be entering both the search and replace expressions in Textmate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   Find: (href=".*?)(%28|%29|%2C)(.+?")
Replace: $1$3

   Find: (href=".*?)(%26)(.+?")
Replace: $1and$3

   Find: (href=".*?)(%20|_)(.+?")
Replace: $1-$3

   Find: (href=".*?)(\.htm)
Replace: $1.html
```

I don't know enough about textmate to help with converting lowercase to all caps.

You also might find [the textmate manual regex section](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions#regular_expressions)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike, this is VERY helpful! The one piece that I still need is the conditional so that it only finds these matches inside of href="".

Comment: Thanks a Million Mike - I was able to make all my updates successfully using your regexes. Here is what I used to convert to lowercase - Find: (href=".*?)(.+?") Replace: \L$0